# &nbsp; causes line break in React

Tags: reactjs

I have one question about `&nbsp;` when I call `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, `&nbsp;` would cause line break.
If i replace them with spaces, it would work
please check my codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-4u16s

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: Why are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` anyway. Putting some text in a div can easily be achieved without this.

Comment: hey @SamuelG my question is why `&nbsp;` would cause line break

Comment: hey @Qwertie, there are some `<p>` and `<b>` in the string

Comment: @Qwertie the OP's content may be html

Comment: The issue is that you are setting the width on the div and `words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together (not break into a new line).`

Comment: so I should set width on child element of div? but I cannot do that, because it might be `<p>` or something else. I mean I am not able to add css on that child element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`&nbsp;`) and a normal space () has different char code.

```js
console.log(example.textContent[0].charCodeAt(0));
console.log(example.textContent[1].charCodeAt(0));
```

```html
<div id="example">&nbsp; </div>
```

When you connect words using `&nbsp;`, the browser will not break the connecting words because of its non-breakable property. Hence, the browser will parse it as if it is one long word.

Just like normal long word, browsers won't break the word unless you have `word-break` style set differently.

I believe the code below can further demonstrate the difference:

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>I&nbsp;have&nbsp;a&nbsp;pen&nbsp;and&nbsp;I&nbsp;have&nbsp;an&nbsp;apple</div>
<div>IhaveapenandIhaveanapple</div>
<div>I have a pen and I have an apple</div>
```

Comment: so your point is that `I&nbsp;am` is considered as one word by browser while `I am` are considered as two words?

Comment: Not exactly, but something like that. `&nbsp;` basically conveys to the browser that "hey, I am a space, but I am non-breakable, so don't break my connection with the characters beside me." I've updated my answer to more accurately convey the meaning.